# $date_of_expiry = time() 60 ;

Tags: setcookie

$date_of_expiry = time() + 60 ;

setcookie( "userlogin", "anonymous", $date_of_expiry, "/" );

echo $_COOKIE("userlogin");

What is wrong with the above code, i get the fatal error

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Psite\set.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

It should be  `$_COOKIE["userlogin"];` instead of `$_COOKIE("userlogin");`

Getting the Cookie Values: `$_COOKIE["userlogin"];`

Setting the Cookie : `setcookie( "userlogin", "anonymous", $date_of_expiry, "/" );`

Answer (score 0):

echo $_COOKIE("userlogin"); Should be with brackets instead:

**echo $_COOKIE["userlogin"];**

Not very eye-catchy since they use ()'s in the first 2 lines :-)